# Assembly compare equal always not equal when used for jump

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-64, flags

I have an array stored starting in `%rsi`, and I want to check if the input is the same with any one of the array elements. I set `%rdx` as `0` and started the loop:

```
loop:
    cmp (%rsi, %rdx, 8), %rdi
    inc %rdx
jne loop
```

But no matter what, it is always not equal, and the loop just goes forever. I have checked in the register view, even if `(%rsi, %rdx, 8)` and `%rdi` are the same, the loop would still repeat itself instead of quitting. And the `eflags` only shows `PF` or `IF`.

Is there anything wrong with the condition structure? How should I do to make it quit the loop when the 2 are equal?

Comment: I completely missed that the `inc %rdx` is before the `jne`. The `inc` will of course change your zero flag. You don't want it there.

Comment: @Jester I see. But what should I do instead to index the array? If I don't increase `%rdx`,  wouldn't `(%rsi, %rdx, 8)` have the same value and then loop forever?

Comment: Right. You can change `inc %rdx` into `lea 1(%rdx), %rdx` as that does not affect flags, or you could rearrange the code so the `inc %rdx` is before the `cmp` and adjust either the starting value to `-1` or the address to `-8(%rsi, %rdx, 8)`.

Comment: @Jester Whoa, this is a big brain for me as a beginner. It worked, thank you!

Comment: The cmp should be just in front of the conditional branch based on the cmp results (for an architecture like this)  so either you do the jmp in the middle before the inc, and then at the end of loop an uncondtional branch or you put the cmp after the inc and adjust the initial and final value of the index.